# selecting proper value from attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select Box for selecting country code :-

```
<div class="selectWrap">
    <select name="countryCode" id="countryCode"></select>
</div>
```

It gets populated using javascript and gets options like follows :-

```
<option data-phone-code="+91">91&nbsp(India)</option>
```

Now I want to select the value only +91.

I was trying this

```
var country = document.getElementById("countryCode");
var prefix = country.options[country.selectedIndex].value;
```

But this returns the Full value with Country.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: well you have no value so it uses the text. Add the value attribute or use the data attribute.

Comment: Donal's answer does it for me. Thanks ! and yes I changed my javascript to ccode.value = "+"+countries[i].phoneCode; Also worked :)

Comment: if donal's answer helped, you should mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use getAttribute, for example:

```
country.options[country.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-phone-code');
```

Comment: It only works without the .value addition because if you add .value it returns undefined

Comment: @speedDeveloper Yes, `getAttribute` returns the value of the attribute - so we don't need to call `.value`.